# Verilog logical error

Tags: verilog

```
module ocircuit (ooutp,s0,s1 ,clk,write,raddA,raddB,wadd,wdata);
  output [3:0] ooutp;
  input clk, write,s0,s1;
  input [2:0] raddA; 
  input [2:0] wadd;
  input [2:0] raddB;
  input [3:0] wdata;

  reg [9:0] ooutp;
  wire [3:0] dataA;
  wire [3:0] dataB;
  reg [9:0] inner;

  regfile y (dataA,dataB,clk,write,raddA,raddB,wadd,wdata);
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (s0==0) begin
      assign inner = dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0];
    end 
    else begin
      assign inner = ((dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0])+inner [9:0]);
    end
    //inner=inner1;
    ooutp =s1?inner [9:0]:10'd0;
  end
endmodule
```

This is the code. `regfile` is a simple register file. In the testbench, `s0 = 0` during the first cycle and `s0 = 1`.

For subsequent cycles, this code should return the value of `A*B+C*D` by using one adder and one multiplier. In the first cycle, when `c0 = 0`, the answer that is saved in `inner` (a register) is right but in the second cycle, when `c0 = 1` the answer is wrong.

Por example: `A=1; B=2; C=1; D=1;`
First cycle: `x=A*B=2`
Second cycle `(C*D)+x=5`

I think there is something wrong with this statement

```
assign inner = ((dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0])+inner [9:0]);
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What are `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`? In your code there are only `dataA` and `dataB`.

Comment: regfile is a register file so for the first cycle A=dataA and B=dataB and for the second cycle as i change the address C=dataA and D=detaB. If this portion is difficult to understand should i post the whole code i.e (test bench,ocircui and regfile)

Answer (score 0):

Although assign can be used from within an `always` block, I think you just wanted to store a value into `inner` depending upon the value of `s0`. To do that, use non-blocking assignments ( `<=` ).

Also, you can directly output to `ooutp` instead of saving the final result in `inner`, avoiding a possible glitch in the multiplexer you instantiate here:

```
ooutp =s1?inner [9:0]:10'd0;
```

Which, by the way, it should be outside the `always` block, in an `assign` line:

```
assign ooutp = s1? inner [9:0]:10'd0;

module ocircuit (ooutp,s0,s1 ,clk,write,raddA,raddB,wadd,wdata);
  output [3:0] ooutp;
  input clk, write,s0,s1;
  input [2:0] raddA; 
  input [2:0] wadd;
  input [2:0] raddB;
  input [3:0] wdata;

  reg [9:0] ooutp;
  wire [3:0] dataA;
  wire [3:0] dataB;
  reg [9:0] inner;

  regfile y (dataA,dataB,clk,write,raddA,raddB,wadd,wdata);
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (s0==0) begin
      inner <= dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0];
    end 
    else begin
      ooutp <= ((dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0])+inner [9:0]);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you     inner <= ((dataA [3:0]*dataB [3:0])+inner [9:0]);
is this statement right?

Comment: Inside the `always @(posedge clk)`, yes.

Comment: I tried what you advised now the 'inner' register have all 'x' at all time, can you think of a reason?

Comment: One or more inputs to your module have not been initialized. Have you got an `initial` block?